# How is VLBI delay calculated, practically?

Tags: astronomy, interferometry, radio, radiometry

I’m working on a research project wherein we are trying to solve a problem very similar to VLBI delay. We have two radio receivers, and we know their locations. We also know at what time one receiver detected a signal, and the coordinates of it’s beam-pointing center. We want to determine at what time the second receiver should’ve seen the signal.

I understand (theoretically) how VLBI delay is calculated (I’ve seen a few different formulas, such as the dot product of a vector between the receivers, and between the receiver and the source) but, practically speaking, how would I actually go about producing numbers?